# referring an equation directly by the number of that equation and not by the rectangular around it

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

Surely most of us have met with the situation in which for referring a special equation, a text draws a rectangular around the equation's number for example the red one in below figures. When it be contacted, we can directly see that section or equation.

[image]

or

[image]

How to eliminate the red rectangular and implement another process for similar aim: For example the color of the equation's number, which must be refereed, be itself red instead of the mentioned rectangular around it.

I am sure that there is a way other people may be asked before but I do not know the category to which my question is related!

Comment: Default it shouldn show up, Probably you use `hyperref` package with settings that show link ba rectangle, Please provide MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem,

Comment: At a guess, that red box is being drawn by your PDF display software and isn't actually in the document. Test this by viewing the document in a different PDF viewer.

Answer (score 6):

This is an artifact hyperref uses to indicate the links when there would be no other indication. Just use

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
```

to make the text be colored without a box.

If you want to remove the border boxes without coloring the text, you can use

```
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
```

or

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}
```

If you want *some* indication of the link, but not bright colors, try

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=dkblue]{hyperref}
```

Comment: A hearty welcome to TeX.SE!!